# Error in writing data frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, break

I'm trying to search a word from the text that I extract from the pdf file which is OCR'd format. This pdf file has multiple pages, so for each page, I'm searching that word, if that word is found then write the **filename**, **status**(Present or Not Present),**Page** on which it is found and what **words** it has found to a dataframe . But the dataframe is giving the status "Present" for all files, I just want like this

```
file_name       Status        Page              words
test1.pdf    "Present"       test1_2,test1_4    gym,school
test2.pdf    "Not Present"     -                 -
test3.pdf    "Present"       test3_1            gym
```

what m I missing in this code.

here is the code

```
    All_files=Sys.glob("*.pdf")
v1 <- numeric(length(All_files))
chk_words=c("Swimming pool","Gym","west","para")
word <- "Gym"
tc=c()
ps=c()
x=list()
df <- data.frame()
Status="Present"

for (i in seq_along(All_files)){


  file_name <- All_files[i]

  cnt <- pdf_info(All_files[i])$pages
  print(cnt)

  for(j in seq_len(cnt)){
    img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(All_files[i], format = 'tiff', pages = j, dpi = 400)
    text <- ocr(img_file)
    ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
    check <- sapply(ocr_text, paste, collapse="")
    junk <- dir(path="D:/Deepesh/R Script/All_PDF_Files/Registration_Certificates_OCR", pattern="tiff")
    file.remove(junk)
    br <-if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(word)))) <= 0) "Not Present"  
    else "Present" 
    print(br)       
    if(br=="Present") {
      v1[i] <- j
      break}

    for(k in chk_words){ 
      br=if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(k)))) <= 0){ print("Not Present") } else {print("Present")}
      if(br == "Present")
        ps=k
      x[[k]]=ps
      tc=unlist(unique(x))
    }




  }

  print(tc)
  Status <- if(v1[i] == 0) "Not Present" else "Present"
  pages <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else 
    paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_name)), "_", v1[i])
  words <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else word
  df <- rbind(df, cbind(file_name = basename(file_name),
                        Status, pages = pages, words = words,tc))


}
```

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are `rbind` ing only when `br == "Present"`

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to see if I was at least able to put those records whose status is present.. but for every page and every file it shows status as "Present"

Comment: You have a nested loop.  Suppose if one of the pages have 'Present', wouldn't the whole document i.e. pdf should show 'Present'.  In that case, you may need to extract the 'br' and check outside the inner loop with `all` or `any`

Comment: Yes, I want that if any pages of the document have "Present" then the document status should be updated as 'Present' else 'Not Present'

Comment: So, in that case, try the suggestion.   I cannot check as this is not reproducible example

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/zWlgzO0Tzu  File could be accessed from here

Comment: What are the packages you used?  I find that there is pdftools, but I guess there are other packages as well

Comment: library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)
library(stringi)
library(TraMineRextras)

Comment: Oh.. I got my mistake I got the code working by your suggestion "if(br=="Present"){
       
        break
      }
      
    }
    df <- rbind(df, cbind(file_name, br))
   " inserted df outside the inner loop

Comment: This may not be helpful advice, but typically text processing is easier done in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option for single word

```
v1 <- numeric(length(All_files))
word <- "school"
df <- data.frame()
Status="Present"

for (i in seq_along(All_files)){


  file_name <- All_files[i]

    cnt <- pdf_info(All_files[i])$pages
    print(cnt)

    for(j in seq_len(cnt)){
      img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(All_files[i], format = 'tiff', pages = j, dpi = 400)
      text <- ocr(img_file)
      ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
      check <- sapply(ocr_text, paste, collapse="")
      junk <- dir(path= paste0(path, "/tiff"), pattern="tiff")
      file.remove(junk)
      br <-if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(word)))) <= 0) "Not Present"  
              else "Present" 
      print(br)       
      if(br=="Present") {
         v1[i] <- j
         break}

    }

    Status <- if(v1[i] == 0) "Not Present" else "Present"
    pages <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else 
     paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_name)), "_", v1[i])
    words <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else word
    df <- rbind(df, cbind(file_name = basename(file_name),
              Status, pages = pages, words = words))


}
```

-output

```
df
#     file_name      Status  pages  words
#1 Amenities.pdf Not Present      -      -
#2      test.pdf     Present test_2 school
```

Comment: @deepesh Regarding the words you are searching.  Do you have a list of words?

Comment: Right now there are 105 words and can be increased in future, right now we can go with school,college, gym, swimming pool.

Comment: @deepesh I updated with a single word case, but I am still not sure how you are looping the multiple words in the document and how the expected output would look like

Comment: Yes that the problem how can we get that word that had match and that too there could be multiple words,again updated my post with expected answer

Comment: The code you posted, can it work for more than two words(right now we are searching for school,, can we search for "gym" and "school")... forgetting about  calculating "pages" column from the code/

Comment: @deepesh I have to check regarding that.  Could you please post as a new question

Comment: posted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420106/check-for-multiple-words-in-string-match-for-text-search-in-r

Comment: searching for more than two words, can it be possible ??

Comment: I tried adding the code for multiple words match, but the column "tc" always  gives NULL....please see the update in the post

Comment: @deepesh Thanks for the update.  I am in the middle of a project.  If I get some time, I will look into it.  The problem is that running this thing takes a bit of time