# Error in Adding a column to a dataframe in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, ocr, concatenation

I'm processing a OCR'd pdf file and extracting text from it and creating a dataframe out of it, What I get is vectors and I'm unable to concatenate them to a single row so that it can be added as a column to a dataframe. from this chunk of code I extract the column for my dataframe

```
chk_words=c("Swimming pool","Gym","west","para")
tp_big=c("swimming pool in a farm","gym","west","north","south")
ps=c()
x=list()
for(i in chk_words){ 
  br=if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(tp_big),tolower(i)))) <= 0){ print("Not Present") } else {print("Present")}

  if(br == "Present")
  ps=i
  x[[i]]=ps
  tc=unlist(unique(x))
  x=paste(tc,collapse=" ")
  }


df11=data.frame(x)
```

I get output(dataframe) as

```
x
Swimming pool Gym west
```

but when I try to implement the same above code in this big code I'm not able to get desired column "x"
This is entire piece of code

```
 library(pdftools)
    library(tesseract)
    library(stringi)
    library(TraMineRextras)
       All_files=Sys.glob("*.pdf")
v1 <- numeric(length(All_files))
chk_words=c("Swimming pool","Gym","west","para")
word <- "Gym"
tc=c()
ps=c()
x=list()
df <- data.frame()
df11 <- data.frame()
Status="Present"

for (i in seq_along(All_files)){


  file_name <- All_files[i]

  cnt <- pdf_info(All_files[i])$pages
  print(cnt)

  for(j in seq_len(cnt)){
    img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(All_files[i], format = 'tiff', pages = j, dpi = 400)
    text <- ocr(img_file)
    ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
    check <- sapply(ocr_text, paste, collapse="")
    junk <- dir(path="D:/Deepesh/R Script/All_PDF_Files/Registration_Certificates_OCR", pattern="tiff")
    file.remove(junk)
    br <-if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(word)))) <= 0) "Not Present"  
    else "Present" 
    print(br)       
    if(br=="Present") {
      v1[i] <- j
      break}

    for(k in chk_words){ 
      sr=if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(k)))) <= 0){ print("Not Present") } else {print("Present")}
      if(sr == "Present")
        ps=k
      x[[k]]=ps
      tc=unlist(unique(x))

    }




  }
  y=paste(tc,collapse=" ")
  #tc=paste(tc,collapse=" ")
  Status <- if(v1[i] == 0) "Not Present" else "Present"
  pages <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else 
    paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_name)), "_", v1[i])
  words <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else word
  df <- rbind(df, cbind(file_name = basename(file_name),
                        Status, pages = pages, words = words,y))


}
```

Right now I get the output like this(gives y as NULL)

file_name   status         pages              words       y
    test1.pdf   Present       test1_1             gym
    test2.pdf   Not Present     -
What I expect is

```
file_name   status         pages              words       y
test1.pdf   Present       test1_1             gym         swimming pool, gym
test2.pdf   Not Present     -
```

Any suggestion where m I going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

P.S [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/zWlgzO0Tzu) is access to sample pdf files; more clarity is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398105/error-in-writing-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

```
checkList = list()
j=0
for(i in chk_words){
   chk=Reduce('|', lapply(i, function(x) any(ocr_text %in% x)))
   if(chk == "TRUE") {
     j = j + 1;
     checkList[[j]] <- i
   }
}
THIRD_COL <- cat(paste(shQuote(unlist(checkList), type="cmd"), collapse=", "))
```

This will give you `"swimming pool", "gym"`
What I did is, if condition satisfied it will store chk_words in checkList (which is a list). Then, I am using `shQuote` into the `paste` to return your desired output.

Comment: Updated the post w.r.t your answer, but still unable to get the "THIRD_COL" column properly.

Comment: You need to debug your code because you have put it under two nested for loops and if statement. I do not see any reason why my block of code wouldn't work.