# Check for multiple words in string match for text search in r

Tags: r, search, dataframe, ocr

Presently I have a code which works for one word search, can we search multiple words and write those matched words in a dataframe? (for clarification, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398105/error-in-writing-data-frame-in-r)) this is [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398105/error-in-writing-data-frame-in-r/46399296?noredirect=1#comment79797253_46399296) solution which works for one word.
Here is the code:

```
 library(pdftools)
 library(tesseract)

 All_files <- Sys.glob("*.pdf")
 v1     <- numeric(length(All_files))
 word   <- "school"
 df     <- data.frame()
 Status <- "Present"

for (i in seq_along(All_files)){
  file_name <- All_files[i]

  cnt <- pdf_info(All_files[i])$pages
  print(cnt)
  for(j in seq_len(cnt)){
      img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(All_files[i], format = 'tiff', pages = j, dpi = 400)
      text     <- ocr(img_file)
      ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
      check    <- sapply(ocr_text, paste, collapse="")
      junk     <- dir(path= paste0(path, "/tiff"), pattern="tiff")
      file.remove(junk)
      br <-if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower(word)))) <= 0) "Not Present"  
              else "Present" 
      print(br)       
      if(br=="Present") {
         v1[i] <- j
         break}
    }

    Status <- if(v1[i] == 0) "Not Present" else "Present"
    pages  <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else 
      paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_name)), "_", v1[i])
    words  <- if(v1[i] == 0) "-" else word
    df     <- rbind(df, cbind(file_name = basename(file_name),
                    Status, pages = pages, words = words))
}
```

Here we are searching for only one word i.e `school`. Can we search for multiple words like `school`, `gym`, `swimming pool`?

**Expected O/P**

```
fileName   Status        Page             Words                    TEXT
test.pdf   Present     test_1             gym            I go gym regularly  
test.pdf   Present     test_3             school     Here is the next school
test1.pdf  Present     test1_4            swimming pool  In swimming pool
test1.pdf  Present     test1_7            gym         next to Gold gym
test2.pdf  Not Present    -               -
```

**fileName**=Name of the File

**Status**=If any word is found then "Present" else "Not Present"

**Page**=Here "_1", "_3" defines the page number on which the word was found;; on page "test_1" word "gym" was found and on page "test_3" word "school" was found.

**Words**= Which all words were found ;; like only "gym" and "school" were found on page 1 and 3 of test.pdf file AND only "swimming pool" and "gym" were found on page 4 and 7 of test1.pdf file.

**TEXT** = It is the text in which the word was found

Any suggestion on the same will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Check out grepl() and use something like "(word|gym|swimming pool)" as the pattern. It will return TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether your words are present or not. I can check it later when I'm on my computer

Comment: ifelse(grepl("Swimming|Hanging", check), "Present", "Not Present").. This returns present or not present, but still unable to append those matched words in dataframe.

Comment: to extract the matched words take a look at `stringr`'s `str_extract_all`. You'll have to do some further cleaning to get unique words pasted together and append them to your data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go through every PDF in your directory with the outside loop. Then you go through all pages of the PDF and extract the text in the inner loop. You want to check for every document whether at least one page contains either `school`, `gym` or `swimming pool`. The returned values you want to use are:

1. a vector of the length of the number of PDF documents containing either `Present` or `Not present`.
2. Three vector with some strings, containing information on which word occurs where and when.

Right?

You can skip a couple of steps in your loop, especially while transforming PDFs to TIFFs and reading texts from them with `ocr`:

```
all_files <- Sys.glob("*.pdf")
strings   <- c("school", "gym", "swimming pool")

# Read text from pdfs
texts <- lapply(all_files, function(x){
                img_file <- pdf_convert(x, format="tiff", dpi=400)
                return( tolower(ocr(img_file)) )
                })

# Check for presence of each word in checkthese
pages <- words <- vector("list", length(texts))
for(d in seq_along(texts)){
  for(w in seq_along(strings)){
    intermed   <- grep(strings[w], texts[[d]])
    words[[d]] <- c(words[[d]], 
                    strings[w][ (length(intermed) > 0) ])
    pages[[d]] <- unique(c(pages[[d]], intermed))
  }
}

# Organize data so that it suits your wanted output
fileName <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(all_files))

Page <- Map(paste0, fileName, "_", pages, collapse=", ")
Page[!grepl(",", Page)] <- "-"
Page <- t(data.frame(Page))

Words    <- sapply(words, paste0, collapse=", ")
Status   <- ifelse(sapply(Words, nchar) > 0, "Present", "Not present")

data.frame(row.names=fileName, Status=Status, Page=Page, Words=Words)        
#       Status                                   Page                      Words
# pdf1 Present                         pdf1_1, pdf1_2         gym, swimming pool
# pdf2 Present pdf2_2, pdf2_5, pdf2_8, pdf2_3, pdf2_6 school, gym, swimming pool
```

It's not as readable as I'd like it to be. Probably because little requirements w.r.t. the output require minor intermediate steps that make the code seem a bit chaotic. It works well, though

Comment: yes For every pdf I search in some predefined words in every page of that pdf, if any of those words is found on that pdf page then capture that word which got matched from the text and append the page number(or page) on which it was found and also append the word in the dataframe that got matched in the text....

Comment: But for every file where there is any of the word present, then it appends all(3 words in our case) the words in the "words" column. Instead I want that only that word gets appended which was matched. your code appends all the 3 words in the dataframe. like "school" this word was not found in the first pdf, but still it appended "school" with "gym" and "swimming pool".

Comment: Also for `page` column, I m expecting the page number on which the words were found but your code pastes filename with "_ present" if the word was found.

Comment: I think it would be great if your questions involve a wanted output. Like this it seems like it's clear what you are doing, but actually there are 5 tweaks here and there, that the answerer only hears about after answering the question you actually posed. I'll update the answer later

Comment: Have updated the post with expected answer(dataframe). kindly have a check

Comment: I  think your updated code  doesn't gives answer in expected format.

Comment: I changed the string values from "strings   <- c("after", "number", "test") " to strings   <- "c("Swimming Pool", "number", "test")"

Comment: This is great. Works for me..this really saved my day..I was really looking for such a solution...appreciate  your time and effort..much Thanks

Comment: One more edit has been updated in the expected output, please if you could check.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a code writing service. I have changed my answer 3 times now and invested a lot of my time. If you have a new problem, please try to solve it yourself and if that doesn't work, open a new question

Comment: Pardon for that.. :( and once again thank you for the effort and time.

Comment: same above post has been re questioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449723/transpose-lists-elements-and-match-to-value-in-r?noredirect=1#comment79859184_46449723